# Import user data using CSV

Tags: plugin-development, import, bulk-import, csv

I want to import user information using a CSV file. I am using the [BP Groups Import User plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-groups-import-users/).

The challenge is to add the first name and last name columns in the CSV file but I cannot get the value to save.

My table is

```
| email      | first name | last name | moderator | admin |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|sm@mail.com | max        | biagi     |      1    |   1   |
```

my code

}else if(isset($_POST['create_user'])) {

```
                    //Create new user
                    $usermeta = array();
                    $usermeta['first_name'] = ucfirst ($first_name);
                    $usermeta['last_name'] = ucfirst ($last_name); 
                    $usermeta['password'] = wp_hash_password( $email );
                    $user_login = strtok($email, '@');
                    $user_id = bp_core_signup_user( $user_login, $email, $email, $usermeta );

                    //Add user to group
                    groups_join_group($group_id, $user_id );

                    //Promote user to group moderator
                    if($mod){
                        groups_promote_member($user_id,$group_id,'mod');
                    }
                    //Promote user to group administrator
                    if($admin){
                        groups_promote_member($user_id,$group_id,'admin');
                    }
                }
```

I can only save email.

Is there another way to get the value from the CSV table?

Comment: Your column names appear incorrect. `first name` and `last name` probably need underscores: `first_name`, `last_name`. Are the underscores missing in your actual CSV. Does changing this help?

Comment: thank you but is not get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE SOLVED

I change my code to wp_insert_user beside bp_core_user_signup

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
                            'user_login' => $user_login,
                            'user_pass' => wp_hash_password( $email ),
                            'first_name' => $first_name,
                            'last_name' => $last_name,
                            'display_name' => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
                            'user_email' => $email,
                            'user_nicename' => $first_name
```